# mongod service not recognized

Tags: mongodb, centos6.5

I have installed mongodb in Centos 6.5. The mongodb folder is in

```
 /usr/mongodb/.
```

But when I run "service mongod start", it shows error:

> The mongod service is unrecognized.

But if we enter `run "/user/mongodb/bin/mongod",` the service starts and works fine. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: follow the link https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mongodb/use-mongodb-to-store-application-data-on-centos-5/

Comment: You have create service for MongoDB?

Comment: No. I only placed the mongodb folder under /usr/.

Answer (score 2):

mongodb  is the core app, but the service is not included in this.
the mongod service is actually part of the mongodb-server installation.

Forgot all about CO6.5, but in CO7, you need to

```
yum install mongodb mongodb-server
```

Before you can start the mongod service.